# why mysqli_connect() returning true even I passing wrong username?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, phpmyadmin

Here's my code.

```
<?php
    $server = "localhost";
    $uname = "replace it with anything";
    $pswd = "";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $uname, $pswd);

    if(!$conn){
        die('Caught');
    }
    else{
        die('Connected');
    }   
?>
```

No matter what I passed in the `mysqli_connect()` as **username**. It always returns `true`. In the case of the wrong password, it shows an error that accesses denied, but I don't know why, no matter what I enter in the username, it always returning true.

Answer (score 7):

It does not return a boolean but an object which represents the connection. You can then check the object for connectivity. From the manual:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

/*
 * This is the "official" OO way to do it,
 * BUT $connect_error was broken until PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting is the object-oriented method (`new mysqli(...)`) is a lot less verbose than the procedural alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
   <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "database") or die($mysqli->error());

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "error";
exit();
}

    ?>
```